# Receiving a Signal from a TLSR8368 with an nRF24L01+

Tags: arduino, packet, wireless, packet-sniffers

I have a remote for my lamp, which uses the TLSR8368 Chip to control the lamp over 2.4Ghz connection. As the remote has additional on/off buttons, I would really like to be able to use these for some other appliances in my house, like relays with Arduinos. Problem is of course how to detect what kind of signal it's sending, and what can receive that. The datasheet of the chip (http://wiki.telink-semi.cn/doc/ds/DS_TLSR8368-E_Datasheet%20for%20Telink%202.4GHz%20RF%20System-On-Chip%20Solution%20TLSR8368.pdf) says that the tranceiver can operate with frequency ranging from 2.400GHz to 2.4835GHz, supports 2Mbps and 250Kbps mode and the Packet looks like this: [image: Packet-2Mbps]
or like this: [image: Packet-250kbps]

So I thought, this looks pretty close to the nRF24L01+. It uses the same Frequencies, the same speed and the protocol looks like this: [image: nRF-Packet] (source: https://lastminuteengineers.com/nrf24l01-arduino-wireless-communication/).

So now I am wondering if I can make these communicate. I have, however, no clue on how to start this endavour, because there are many open variables - I don't know the precise frequency, and also, the nrf24l01 additionally needs a 'pipe' to listen to - it discards all other packages that do not contain this pipe, as it doesn't offer a promiscuous mode.

So now I'd need to try out 128*2^40 different combinations of channels and pipes, which is obviously unfeasible. After some googling, I've found this link: http://yveaux.blogspot.com/2014/07/nrf24l01-sniffer-part-1.html, which explains a packet-sniffer for the nrf24l01, but it comes with a lot of caveats and before I invest the time to try this out (and install Windows for that...) I am wondering if it's even worth the time, if what I'm trying to do is completely impossible anyway, or if there is an easier way to do this (also if this easier way means not using the nrf24l01 after all but buying another receiver-chip altogether).

Can anybody provide some help?

Comment: Asking us to reverse engineer device communication is way too broad of a question.

Comment: I know it is, but I am really not asking that. I just have never done that before, so I'm really just asking if it is even feasible or if there are obvious reasons why this is not possible. To my Eye the protocols look similar enough that it may be worth a shot, but like I said I have no experience at all in that regard.

Comment: Asking if something is possible is still considered too broad. There is more in between using the same frequency and packet structure. And asking about hardware compatibility isn't really about programming either.

Comment: I understand. But then again, if you know what it is that's there apart from frequency and packet Structure you already know more than me, and these kinds of hints are what I'm looking for. Regarding the fact that it's no programming question: I thought so too, but I looked at the other stackexchange Forums and didn't find anything appropriate (this doesn't fit in serverfault or Hardwarerecommendations), so I figured as my question is basically about package compatibility here is as good a place as any - again, if you know better I'm glad to be told.

Comment: They are at least both using GFSK modulation. And because there isn't a better suited SE site, doesn't mean it's on-topic here. Stack Overflow isn't a catch-all site. Also SE sites aren't forums. They aren't meant for discussions.

Comment: First of all thanks for the hint with the GFSK modulation - seems like just another thing making it more improbable to be easily compatible? Even though if both use it.. what do I know. Regarding the second - You're right, but that's why I then asked in a "are these packages compatible enough that it may work"-way, which more or less fits the scheme - grasping straws here, I know. I also no that SE sites aren't a forum, I just lacked a better word for it, sorry.